# Discord.js - show deleted message author and number of their deleted messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a simple code prune message code. but I want to improve it

```
  const number = args[0]

  let messages = await message.channel.fetchMessages({
    limit: number
  });

     let message = await message.channel.bulkDelete(messages, true);

    message.reply(`${message.size} messages deleted.`)
```

I want to do this by showing the name of the members whose message has been deleted and the number of messages that have been deleted next to it.
for example;

```
23 messages deleted

Alex#0001 : 10
John#0002 : 13
```

how can i

Answer (score 1):

I think the best option would be looping through the messages and then adding 1 for each message to count in object